# Как спарсить определенную строчку на сайте Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Хочу спарсить определенную строку на сайте (к примеру температура погоды с яндекса), на сайте очень много тегов `<span>` с классом `temp__value temp__value_with-unit`. Как я могу спарсить определенную строку. зная полный путь к селектору (`body > div.b-page__container > div.content.content_compressed.i-bem > div.content__top > div.fact.card.card_size_big > div.fact__temp-wrap > a > div.temp.fact__temp.fact__temp_size_s > span.temp__value.temp__value_with-unit`)?

Comment: в bs4 можно селекторы использовать, т.е.: `soup.select_one('body > div.b-page__container > div.content.content_compressed.i-bem > div.content__top > div.fact.card.card_size_big > div.fact__temp-wrap > a > div.temp.fact__temp.fact__temp_size_s > span.temp__value.temp__value_with-unit')`

Answer (score -1):

```
# я как то так делал
def get_data_2(cars, params=None):
    datas = []
    for i in range( len(cars) ):
        url1 = cars[i]
        url2 = url1['title']
        data = requests.get(url2, headers= HEADER, params=params)
        data = data.text

        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
        items = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'offer')

        for item in items:

            datas.append({
                'brand': item.find('h1', class_= 'offer__title').get_text(),
                'price': item.find('div', class_ = 'offer__price').get_text(strip=True).replace('\xa0', ''),
                'city' : item.find('dd', class_='value').get_text(),
        })
```